# Why node.js async module stops after the first step using async.eachLimit(array, limit, function, callback)?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, concurrency

If I use this code:

```
async.eachLimit(body.photos.photo, 10, function(photo) {

         var flickr_getphoto_path = ".....";

         request.get({url: flickr_host_url + flickr_getphoto_path, json: true}, function(error, response, body) {
           if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

             console.log("SIZES LENGTH: " + body.sizes.size.length);
             var source_url = body.sizes.size[body.sizes.size.length - 1].source;
             request(source_url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path_for_downloads + path.basename(source_url)));
           }
         });

}
```

The processing stops after 10 requests (i.e. after the first cycle).
There should be 10 cycles.

Does somebody know why it doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set up the async function wrong. The third argument (the iterator function) takes two parameters: the item being iterated upon, and a callback to tell async that it's done. You're missing (and thus never calling) the callback, so async doesn't know that it's time to do the next batch.

```
var async = require('async');

async.eachLimit(body.photos.photo, 10, cacheOnePhoto, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Processing complete');
  };
})

function cacheOnePhoto(photo, done){
  var flickr_getphoto_path = ".....";
  request.get({
    url: flickr_host_url + flickr_getphoto_path, 
    json: true
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log("SIZES LENGTH: " + body.sizes.size.length);
      var source_url = body.sizes.size[body.sizes.size.length - 1].source;
      request(source_url).pipe(
        fs.createWriteStream(path_for_downloads + path.basename(source_url))
      );
      done(null);
    } else {
      done('Request error for '+flickr_getphoto_path);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Note I'm not sure how piping the files works. You may have to find how to set a callback for when the pipe is complete, and only then call done().