# My grunt plugin that is supposed to create a .ctl file for every folder in a directory will do no more than 4 before it ends

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

So, as stated in my title I'm making this grunt plugin that is supposed to get all the files specified in `cwd` and write to `dest` a .ctl file for each one. In each .ctl file there is content that is specified in the `content` variable in my plugin.

What it does, however, is do it for a maximum of 4 files and then it ends the task logging `grunt.log.ok`.

I appreciate that this might be pretty hard to debug by just looking at the code so if anyone wants (and has the time) to download the npm package and see for themselves it can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ctl).

Many thanks in advance for any help provided.

Here is my plugin code:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {


grunt.registerMultiTask('ctl', 'HELLO', function () {
// Modules
var async = require('async');
var done = this.async();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var os = require('os');
var content;
var fileName;

process.setMaxListeners(0);

function begin(file) {
  grunt.file.mkdir(path.dirname(file.dest));

  fileName = file.src.toString().split('/').slice(-1)[0];

  grunt.log.write('Creating control file for ' + fileName + '\n');

  content = 'USER=' + file.username + '\n' +
    'PASSWORD=' + file.password + '\n' +
    'FILENAME=' + fileName + '.zip' + '\n' +
    'Name=' + fileName + '\n' +
    'Description_vod__c=' + file.description;

  grunt.file.write(file.dest + '.ctl', content, {encoding: 'utf8'});

}

async.eachLimit(this.files, os.cpus().length, begin, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
});

grunt.log.ok('ctling complete ◕ ‿ ◕');

done();
  });
};
```

Here is the important grunt file code:

```
ctl: {
        default_options: {
            files: [{
                filter: 'isDirectory',
                expand: true,
                cwd: './test/fixtures/',
                src: ['*'],
                dest: './test/expected/',
                username: 'test@test.com',
                password: 'test',
      description: 'This is a description'
            }]
        }
    },
```

Comment: Take a closer look at this line: `async.eachLimit(this.files, os.cpus().length, begin,...`. Pretty sure it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I don't full understand that line if I'm honest. Due to time constraints and a very basic knowledge of Node I've kinda hacked it together. All I know is that without that it doesn't work. Not the answer you were hoping for I'm sure!

Comment: To clarify, without that line when the function 'begin' runs it says that the argument 'file' is undfined

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17236726/2057919); I'm pretty sure you have the same problem. You need to accept a second parameter, a callback function, in `begin`, and you need to call that callback when you are done processing a batch.

Comment: Thanks for your help dude!